# PuTTY -m command option failing with "unable to open ... file" on Windows 7

Tags: batch-file, windows-7, putty

I'm trying to make an automatic PuTTY login using a batch file. I have this:

```
start "title" "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" "server_name@server_IP" -pw "password" -m "commands_to_execute.txt"
```

Everything works on my Windows 10 machine but in Windows 7, the command option `-m` does not work. The error message is:

> unable to open command file:"commands_to_execute.txt"

I have tried changing all paths to "C:\Program Files\PuTTY", setting the working directory `/D`, working in the actual directory and I also add the path to the enviroment variables in:

> Advance system settings >Enviroment Variables

I have also used plink instead of putty.

What is happening?

Answer (score 2):

It is very unlikely that your problem has anything to do with Windows 7 vs Windows 10.

Most likely the working directory for your batch file execution on Windows 7 is not set to the folder, where the `commands_to_execute.txt` file is stored.

Possible solutions are:

- Set the working directory the same way you have set it on Windows 10
- Use a full path to the script file:

  ```
  -m "C:\path\to\commands_to_execute.txt"
  ```
- Set working directory for PuTTY explicitly using:

  ```
  start "title" /D "C:\path\to" "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe"  ...
  ```
- Or, if the script file is in the same folder as your batch file, you can use:

  ```
  start "title" /D "%~dp0" "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe"  ...
  ```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use plink.exe for this not putty.exe, just replace:

```
start "title" "C:\Program Files\PuTTY\plink.exe" "server_name@server_IP" -pw "password" -m "commands_to_execute.txt"
```

or make it even easier:

```
cd C:\Program Files\PuTTY\
plink.exe -ssh pi@192.168.1.166 -P 22 -pw P@SSWRD ~/script.sh
plink.exe -ssh pi@192.168.1.166 -P 22 -pw P@SSWRD -m commands.txt 
pause
```

either of the two lines work.

Comment: When using the **`CD`** command, you should really use its **`/D`** option, _unless the 'current drive' is known to be the same at the time it is used_.

Comment: While you maybe right with Plink (though we do not really know what OP is up to), you do not address the OP's problem at all. Your code will have the same problem as OP has.

Comment: Yes, the problem is still there. Thanks

Comment: have you tried using the full location of the directory? what privileges are allowed to .bat file?

Comment: Yes I tried. The .bat and .txt files have all privileges allowed